# Best Typescript Typing for JSON String { String : String[] }

Tags: typescript

I have a JSON file that I would like to use in typescript, but not quite sure how to define the type/interface.

It basically defines a layout of a virtual keyboard. So it will have a layoutName, then each row will have a name.

The layout name (e.g "default", "emoji"). I want to be a generic string that can be any value, so I was thinking record type. The row names should be consistently the same, but they have to be accessed dynamically so I'm thinking they should be records too?

Here is an example from the JSON file.

```
{
  "default": {
    "row1": [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6",
      "7",
      "8",
      "9",
      "0",
      "-",
      "=",
      "Backspace"
    ],
    "row1_shift": [
      "!",
      "@",
      "#",
      "$",
      "%",
      "^",
      "&",
      "*",
      "(",
      ")",
      "_",
      "+",
      "Backspace"
    ],
},
"emoji": {
  "row1" : []
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Are all the rows [always required](https://tsplay.dev/w6BA6w) or are they [optional](https://tsplay.dev/WPjEZN)?  Can you spell out what the row names are?

Comment: They're technically optional, but I'm fine for "optional" to mean "can be empty collection". I currently have 
`interface KeyboardLayout {
    row1: string[];
    row1_shift: string[];
    row2: string[];
    row2_shift: string[];
    row3: string[];
    row3_shift: string[];
    row4: string[];
    row4_shift: string[];
    row5: string[];
    row5_shift: string[];
}
interface KeyboardLayouts {
    default: KeyboardLayout;
    ...
}`

Though there could be any number of layouts, not just "default". Both rows and layout names need to be able to be accessed dynamically.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "dynamically"?  Perhaps with a [mre] of how you'd use it?

Comment: Something like this can be called:
`let currentRow = Application.keyboard[layout]["row" + index + modifier]`

Where index = number, and modifier is something like "_shift". A getProperty function that allows that might be a better solution, or else a type so that I can simply access everything with `[key]`

Comment: So [like this](https://tsplay.dev/w8A3EN)?  See how the compiler is able to figure out that the template literal is of the right type to index into `virtualKeyboard[layout]`

Comment: That's pretty awesome. Would happily mark that as solution. The rowNames type in particular is something I love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you do want to use a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) for the top-level keys of your interface.  For the next level down, though, if you have a set of known keys you should probably use them, even if you have to access the properties dynamically.  For example:

```
type RowNames = `row${1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5}${"" | "_shift"}`;
interface VirtualKeyboard {
  [layoutName: string]: Partial<Record<RowNames, string[]>>;
}
```

This is equivalent to

```
/* type VirtualKeyboard = {
    [x: string]: {
        row1?: string[] | undefined;
        row1_shift?: string[] | undefined;
        row2?: string[] | undefined;
        row2_shift?: string[] | undefined;
        row3?: string[] | undefined;
        row3_shift?: string[] | undefined;
        row4?: string[] | undefined;
        row4_shift?: string[] | undefined;
        row5?: string[] | undefined;
        row5_shift?: string[] | undefined;
    };
} */
```

I'm just using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to express `RowNames` succinctly, and [the `Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) and [the `Record<K, V>` utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to express the subproperty type without repetition.  But it's the same thing.

---

Then, when it comes to reading properties, you can do something like this:

```
const virtualKeyboard: VirtualKeyboard = {/*...*/}

for (const layout in virtualKeyboard) {
  for (const index of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] as const) {
    for (const modifier of ["", "_shift"] as const) {
      let currentRow = virtualKeyboard[layout][`row${index}${modifier}`];
      if (!currentRow) continue;
      for (const key of currentRow) {
        console.log(key.toUpperCase());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The first loop iterates over all the keys of `virtualKeyboard`.  The key `layout` is of type `string`, and it's okay to index into `virtualKeyboard` with it because it has a `string` index signature.  For the next loops I am using [`const`-asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) arrays of indices and modifiers so that the compiler knows that they are of type `1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5` and `"" | "_shift"` respectively.

At this point you can use an actual [template literal *value*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) `` `row${index}${modifier}` `` to index into `virtualKeyboard[layout]`.  The compiler is able to treat that as being of a template literal *type* (due to [improvements in TS 4.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#template-string-type-improvements); before this you might have needed `as const` also), and so it sees that the key is one of the known keys of the subproperty.

And that means it knows that `currentRow` is of type `string[] | undefined` (it's possibly `undefined` because of the `Partial<>` in the definition.  If you know that it will never be `undefined`, then you can leave out the `Partial<>`).  So once we check it for `undefined`, we can iterate over it and the compiler expects that every `key` will be a `string`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gdwHIEMC2EDOUC8UAGATogCQDeAjFAD5QBMNUAzIwCyMCsAvuQES+NeAfUwALAJYAzYLy74A3AChxAO2ARCklAGNoANXGFgAVxQAbANIQQAIzgpCAEyhlFUKAG0zKEHGPBUDAAuKExgQlUAcwBdEIAFB2BxcwAeGAhtOCc0xECsABpQ8KiPaIA+MqUuRUUAegAqKFBIKAMjU0trOwdnPFd3dw8ADxCwiJUYkP6BmeIECgB+UeKJ0sZjFUcISVUIRyUZ2cQKEQlpJaLxyLXaDa2dlT2Dw-c5uguxkuj1ze3d-bcLygb1OUmAHxW12+t1+DyegJecyYEKuNygdz+jwBQOBiCYoPOy1R0PRsP+z0RiFYKK+P3u5IRhzmrAJ4KJtJh9KxFKZiA4NNWJIxcOxQLmHFZAqhdMx8JmXCqUHqtRqmRUYSgADdDCZzFZbPYnCE2rrOgaergXIDePcUMYzDIpozeHMKLwQh5Ge5eG78l6oLw6Lw-S9eExg-7eKwI6GODHDrwAGzxma8ADsKYGvAAHJnvQBOPMBgAMRd4AFoyzgywAhHQAa0wYB0EF4jOiIazrtZ7s8kYAhGWAAJlgDEZZIZYApGWAHplgBkZfqZYAFGWAJRloRlgDUtYbTZbbZmHcBXE7vAgaDgACtxL3pt7Xb3SufFAqapIslBV2qNd4vj+FAqhajqHT6t0Tgbla7jfoQv7-sAIG-EMUBwJIngUIUdCFEwhSsIUHDfCg2BITBT5QPBiFwOqyE3o4UjiBo6GYR4-CFMIYhgrwJFkbRYQUf6ZgQMh2jGIQhAQGo8AIJa2rtHqXSGo4Xg+H4wDRB4RCkGQqhbEMPBkAxTEaHI0Q8u4Ui-v24mSdJwCyTBapJCoxgQJZVE-n+AnIfW1isVAdlSTJiBCTi-5wCJAB0ZhwJEq7+SA0XAHAACqYCQIQADCpEQKuG4bp51Tyu+1RAA)